# I'm use rbenv to install ruby but I 'm getting this error when using "GEM" -> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sudo, rbenv, rbenv-gemset

I install ruby follow this steps https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv on my MacBook M1 Sonoma 14.2.1.
All went perfect until I need to use "gem install bundler".

terminal:

```
    gem install bundler
    ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/pedrodiogo/.local/share/gem/specs
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:406:in mkdir' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:406:in fu_mkdir'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:384:in block (2 levels) in mkdir_p' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:382:in reverse_each'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:382:in block in mkdir_p' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:374:in each'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:374:in mkdir_p' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/source.rb:151:in fetch_spec'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/resolver/api_specification.rb:92:in spec' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:98:in add_always_install'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:322:in resolve_dependencies' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:205:in install_gem'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:230:in block in install_gems' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:223:in each'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:223:in install_gems' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:169:in execute'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:327:in invoke_with_build_args' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:252:in invoke_command'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:192:in process_args' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:150:in run'
    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in run' /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/gem:10:in
```

terminal:

```
gem env            
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.4.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 patchlevel 53) [arm64-darwin23]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/pedrodiogo/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/pedrodiogo/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - arm64-darwin-23
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
     - /Users/pedrodiogo/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/shims
     - /opt/homebrew/bin
     - /opt/homebrew/sbin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

terminal:

```
gem env home
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
```

And one more question, I need to install rails should I use the "sudo" command or not?
Could you help me? thank you in advance!

I try to fix this looking online but I couldn't. I try change the permissions, I try to reinstall brew and nothing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ownership of your directory there, probably you did something with `sudo` that you shouldn't have and that directory is owned by `root` and not your own user. Probably you need to do a `sudo chown -R $USER /Users/pedrodiogo/.local`